# How to dumpxml to a file when authentication enabled?

Tags: kvm, qemu, virsh, libvirt

I set up authentication for the libvirtd, because it has right to operate pools and hence to write to raw disk devices.

Now I need to dumpxml from existing domain. But the dumpxml command has no output file parameter - it always dump things to the stdout. And if I use stdout redirection, I have troubles with authentication, which is done throug the standard inputs and output.

I still could copy text from the terminal with the mouse middle-key, but I search for some more convenient way.

Comment: What specifically is the problem with authentication?  Redirecting stdout won't impact your ability to enter credentials.  You can implement libvirt authentication without requiring passwords (that is, you can restrict it to certain group or user ids, for example).

Comment: Well, I could enter credentials blindly and remove first two lines from the output by a script. It was I'm going to do anyway. But I'd like to know what is the supposed way. And I prefer not to install complex systems like kerberos to bypass inputting password. All other methods require me to store credentials somewhere in a file and I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting a "complex system" like Kerberos.  Good luck.